# Magento 2.3 Class does not exist

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I'm using the command: `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and receives an error

```
Class Magiccart\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimonial does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyy

Please create a file name Testimonial.php under the Model\ResourceModel Folder
Then The error is removed Automatically.

like this :

```
class Testimonial extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb

{

    //Do Your Stuff Here.......    

}
```